# How to separate a string by words using arrays and function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Code the I am trying to do:

```
function look(str) {
  var stringArr = ['JAVA'];
  var arr = [];
  var novaString = ''

  for(i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
    arr = stringArr;
  }
  console.log(arr)
  return arr;
} look('arr');
```

I Want the output to look like this:

```
[J]
[JA]
[JAV]
[JAVA]
[JAV]
[JA]
[J]
```

There's no more details to add.

Comment: You're not using your `str` argument + your `stringArr` is harcoded in the function. What do you want the function to do exactly?

Comment: I want the function to look like the output

Comment: What we **think** you are wanting has nothing to do with the question you asked

Comment: You probably want to rewrite the question to reflect that? @DominickL.Bakex

Comment: I edited the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
    var k='JAVA';
var a=k.split('');
var e=[];
a.forEach((el)=>{
    e.push(el);
console.log(e);
})
for(let i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
{
    e.pop();
    console.log(e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: `JAVA` is string not Array

Comment: Edited, please check now.

Comment: did you use either any framework to do that or any tools to facilitate?

Comment: Nop. Pure JavaScript

Comment: @DominickL.Bakex `split` is JS function.

Comment: split is a js function which splits your string into an array based on the value you have provide in the split function. If a string has , and you use split(',') on your string an array will be created with all the elements separated by ,

Comment: if the answer is what you want mark it as correct so other users can get help too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear but may be you want this:

```
function look(str) {
    var stringArr = str;

    for(i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) 
    {
        console.log("[" + stringArr.substring(0,i+1) + "]");
    }
    for(i = (stringArr.length - 2); i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        console.log("[" + stringArr.substring(0,i+1) + "]");
    }
} 
look('arr');
```